# Gerando PDF com MPDF apartir de BLOB

Tags: php, blob, mpdf

Bom estou precisando gerar um PDF a partir de um campo BLOB salvo no banco de dados, a minha ideia é da possibilidade de fazer upload de PDF transformando ele em BLOB para não ocupar espaço em disco e facilitar o transporte do mesmo.

Estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
include("../pdf/mpdf60/mpdf.php");

$mpdf=new mPDF(); 

$mpdf->WriteHTML($registros->BLO_PDFXX_ARQUI);


$mpdf->Output();
exit;
```

onde o `$registros->BLO_PDFXX_ARQUI` é o código que estou tentando fazer. Porém ai vem a pergunta, com MPDF tenho condição de fazer isto ?

Minha outra duvida é existe algum gerenciado que me facilitaria neste caso de conteúdo BLOB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para gerar PDF a partir  de um código HTML eu recomendo o Wkhtmltopdf

http://wkhtmltopdf.org/

ou ainda mais simples HTML2PDF

http://html2pdf.fr/en/default

ambos são práticos de utilizar e já trazem alguns exemplos em seu pacote.

Qualquer duvida me disponho a auxiliar.

Comment: Este gera para mim de BLOB para pdf ?

Comment: Para isso basta usar o php para tratar o BLOB e criar um html com o contéudo e formatação desejada.

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ibase-blob-echo.php

Caso você não esteja utilizando firebird essa é outra forma bem simples: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556773/php-display-image-blob-from-mysql

Comment: quando estou dando echo esta dando erro interno do servidor

Comment: estou pesquisando desta forma aqui $bloo = ibase_blob_echo($registros->BLO_PDFXX_ARQUI);
echo $bloo;

Comment: no log de erro do php deu este erro PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function ibase_blob_echo()

Comment: Dessa forma é mais simples, a função ibase_blob_echo é uma função disponivel pela library do firebird.

echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode(** $BLOB **).'"/>';

Comment: Porém não é uma imagem, na verdade o processo é o seguinte, o cara faz upload de um arquivo .pdf transformo ele em blob e salvo no banco, agora quero recuperar este arquivo .pdf. O problema ocorre ao recuperar os dados BLOB

Comment: Você pode usar o mesmo código echo '<a href="data:**TIPO**;base64,'.base64_encode(** $BLOB **).'" download > Baixar PDF </a> ' , basta alterar o tipo do arquivo retornado e a tag.